# Unknown type name 'UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier' error in swift

Tags: swift

any ideas why am I getting an "unknown type name UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier" in this code?

I'm basically adding external obj-c class to an existing project.I've added the Bridging-Header.h file. Not sure what else I have to do?

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier _backgroundTask;
```

And in below line, I get " Use of undeclared identifier 'UIApplication' " this error.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self._backgroundTask];
    self._backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

if I import these two lines then

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

I get "1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64" error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an iOS Static Library.
I included this lines and the problem was solved.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

I´ve found here:
https://github.com/TransitApp/SVHTTPRequest/issues/49